# Atmosphere: How to unsubscribe from a broadcast

Tags: jersey, atmosphere

Simple question, how do you unsubscribe from a broadcast from the Java API ? I can't find anything in the API that stands out and I can't find anything on Google.

Stack: Java 7, Atmosphere 2.2.3, Atmosphere-Jersey 2.2.3, Servlet 3, Tomcat 7

**This is how I'm subscribing:**

```
@Path("subscription")
public class CurrencyPairSubscription {

    @GET
    @Suspend
    @Path("{pair}")
    public Broadcastable subscribeToQuote(@PathParam("pair") String pair,
            @Context final BroadcasterFactory broadcasterFactory) {

        return new Broadcastable(broadcasterFactory.lookup(pair, true));
    }
}
```

**This is how I'm broadcasting:**

```
public class BroadcasterServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void init() {

        System.out.println("Broadcast Servlet init");
        AtmosphereFramework framework = (AtmosphereFramework) getServletContext()
                .getAttribute("AtmosphereServlet");
        MetaBroadcaster metaBroadcaster = framework.metaBroadcaster();


        metaBroadcaster.scheduleTo(RandomQuoteGenerator.generate()
                .getIdentifier(), RandomQuoteGenerator.retrieveLastQuote(), 15,
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a client side js/jquery you can call `unsubscribe` method to close connection.

```
socket.unsubscribe(request);
```

While in the server side, you can use AtmosphereResource [close](http://atmosphere.github.io/atmosphere/apidocs/org/atmosphere/cpr/AtmosphereResource.html#close()) method to unsubscribe the user.Note you can try to inject `AtmosphereResourceFactory` to have an access to all atmosphereResource connection.

```
@Inject
private AtmosphereResourceFactory resourceFactory;
```

then find the unique UUID and close the connection

```
resourceFactory.find(userUUID).close();
```

Comment: It looks like I don't need to unsubscribe on the server side and can just let the client handle it. Is that correct ?

Comment: well yes,typically client side do the unsubscribe.